# How do I connect admin page in django with custom auth backend?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-authentication

I used a custom auth backend in my django project to connect users, my problem is that i'm not able to connect using the admin interface anymore.
this is my custom auth files :
**auth_backends.py:**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
from django.db.models import get_model


class StudentModelBackend(ModelBackend):
def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
    try:
        user = self.user_class_s.objects.get(username=username)
        if user.check_password(password):
            return user
    except self.user_class_s.DoesNotExist:
        return None

def get_user(self, user_id):
    try:
        return self.user_class_s.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    except self.user_class_s.DoesNotExist:
        return None

@property
def user_class_s(self):
    if not hasattr(self, '_user_class'):
        self._user_class = get_model(*settings.CUSTOM_USER_MODEL.split('.', 2))
        if not self._user_class:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured('Could not get student model')
    return self._user_class


class ProfessorModelBackend(ModelBackend):
def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
    try:
        user = self.user_class_p.objects.get(username=username)
        if user.check_password(password):
            return user
    except self.user_class_p.DoesNotExist:
        return None

def get_user(self, user_id):
    try:
        return self.user_class_p.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    except self.user_class_p.DoesNotExist:
        return None

@property
def user_class_p(self):
    if not hasattr(self, '_user_class'):
        self._user_class = get_model(*settings.CUSTOM_USER_MODEL_P.split('.', 2))
        if not self._user_class:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured('Could not get student model')
    return self._user_class
```

**settings.py:**

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
'authentification.auth_backends.StudentModelBackend',
'authentification.auth_backends.ProfessorModelBackend',
)

CUSTOM_USER_MODEL = 'forum.Student'
CUSTOM_USER_MODEL_P = 'forum.Professor'
```

I tried this solution :
    from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

```
admin.autodiscover()
admin.site.login = login_required(admin.site.login)
```

but it redirect me to the user auth interface instead of admin interface.

Could someone help me please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I Found the solution, 
i just have to tell django to try connecting using the original backend if the user isnt a student or professor.
just add  'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend' in settings.py

settings.py :

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
'authentification.auth_backends.StudentModelBackend',
'authentification.auth_backends.ProfessorModelBackend',
'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The default `login_required` decorator will default to the settings.py `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`. However, you can also explicitly tell it which login view to use by passing the `login_url` keyword argument.

https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.8.x/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py#L39

This may be used with the generic `login_required` view and my samples below show more precise conditionals by using the `user_passes_test` decorator.

For instance:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

def superuser_required(*args, **kwargs):
    return user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser, login_url='admin:login')(*args, **kwargs)

def custom_login_required(*args, **kwargs):
    return user_passes_test(lambda u: getattr(u, 'is_custom_user', False), login_url='custom-url-name-from-urls-py')(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then you should be able to use this new decorate as you have above with the generic `login_required`:

```
admin.site.login = custom_login_required(admin.site.login)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, in both case : admin - normal user , he try to connect using my custom auth for normal users, he fail to connect if the user is admin, how to make him use the default auth backend when it is an admin